# What exactly does void * mean

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have seen `void *` explained as a pointer to an unused chunk of memory. I have also seen `void *` described as a pointer to any type, or a pointer to any type can be cast to `void *`. 
From what I know, `int *` means a pointer to type `int`. So keeping this in mind, what does `void *` mean literally? Is it a pointer to type `void`? This doesn't seem right because I did not know that `void` could be a type.

Comment: Think of `void` as a bit of a wildcard in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void *` is a pointer to `void`.

#### C11: 6.3.2.3 Pointers:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.

The compiler will not let you dereference a `void*` pointer because it does not know the size of the object pointed to but you need to cast `void *` type pointer to the right type before you dereference it.

Comment: Indeed. ``void *`` is basically the universal pointer. You typically use it as a *handle*, which is a way of essentially obfuscating the type of a pointer to prevent the user from doing things they shouldn't do, since ``C`` lacks the concept of ``private`` and ``public`` for structs, and you can't dereference a ``void *`` without knowing what it already is. It can also be used to allow you to have a function accept different types and have a secondary parameter tell the function how it should handle it (primitive generics).

Comment: I'd avoid the term "handle" here, as it has been used in the past to refer to a `void **` (specifically, in the Classic Mac OS Memory Manager API).

Answer (score 3):

Let's begin with this example:

```
    int a = 65;
    int *q = &a;
    void *p = q;
    char *c = p;
```

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [qiniudn.com](http://cizixs.u.qiniudn.com/pointer.png))</sub>

we define an int variable a, and an int pointer q pointing to it. p in the `void *` pointer.
The beginning address of a is `0x8400`(just for simplicity).

#### A pointer is an address, no more.

No matter what type of pointer, they have the same memory size, and their value is an address.
So,

```
printf("%p, %p", *p, *q);
```

will display:

```
0x8400, 0x8400
```

#### Type: how you interpret the date

As you see in the graph, the data in memory is `65000000`(this is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). If we want to use it, we have to specify what it is! And type does that.

```
printf("%d %c", *p, *q);
```

If we print it as integer, we get `65`. If we print them as char, we get `A`(asciicode).

And `p + 1` pointer to `0x8401`, `q + 1` points to `0x8404`.

#### `void *`: a universal type

According to wikipedia:

> A program can probably convert a pointer to any type of data (except a function pointer) to a pointer to void and back to the original type without losing information, which makes these pointers useful for polymorphic functions.

Yes, `void *` define a trivial unit of pointer, it can be converted to any pointer and vise versa. But you can't dereference it, because it doesn't specify a type.

If you want to manipulator on bytes, you should always use `void *`.

#### Isn't `char *` the same as `void *`

Not exactly.

> The C language standard does not explicitly guarantee that the different pointer types have the same size.

You can't always hope `char *` have the same size on different platforms.

And converting `char *` to `int *` can be confusing, and mistakes can be made.

Answer (score 2):

It means: a pointer to some memory, but this pointer does not contain any information about the *type* of data that may be stored in that memory.

This is why it's not possible to dereference a `void *`: the operation of dereferencing (and obtaining an rvalue, or writing through an lvalue) requires that the bits in the memory location be interpreted as a particular type,  but we don't know which type to interpret the memory as.

The onus is on the programmer to make sure that data read in matches the type of data read out. The programmer might help himself in this by converting the `void *` to a pointer to an object type.

It's useful if you want to have a common interface for dealing with memory of multiple possible types, without requiring the user to do a lot of casting. for example `free()` takes a `void *` because the type information isn't necessary when doing the `free` operation.

Answer (score 2):

`void *` is a pointer to data of unspecified type.  As such, it can't be used directly; it must be cast to a usable datatype before it can be dereferenced.

Comment: Thankyou for clarifying that it has to be cast before dereferencing.